# reverse method for generic pair in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, interface, reverse

```
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Pair<Integer> p = new DefaultPair<>(3,5);
    p.reverse();
    final Pair<Integer> q = new DefaultPair<>(5,3);
    }

}

public interface Pair<F> {
    F first();
    F second();
    F reverse();
}

public class DefaultPair<F> implements Pair<F> {
    private final F first; 
    private final F second; 
    private F reverseFirst; 
    private F reverseSecond; 


  public DefaultPair(F first, F second){//constructor 
  this.first = first; 
  this.second = second; 
    }

// method that is not working    
 @Override
  public F reverse() {

    this.reverseFirst = second; 
    this.reverseSecond = first; 

    System.out.println(this);
    return (F)this; 
   }

 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((first == null) ? 0 : first.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((second == null) ? 0 : second.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof DefaultPair))
        return false;
    DefaultPair<F> other = (DefaultPair) obj;
    if (first == null) {
        if (other.first != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!first.equals(other.first))
        return false;
    if (second == null) {
        if (other.second != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!second.equals(other.second))
        return false;
    return true;
 }

@Override
  public F first(){
      return first;
  }

 @Override
  public F second(){
      return second; 
  }


 @Override
 public String toString() {
      return "<" + first + ", " + second + ">";
    }

}

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestDefaultPair {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final Pair<Integer> p = new DefaultPair<>(3, 5);
        final Pair<Integer> q = new DefaultPair<>(5, 3);
         assertEquals(3, p.first().intValue());
         assertEquals(5, p.second().intValue());
         assertEquals("<3, 5>", p.toString());
         assertTrue(p.equals(p));
         assertFalse(p.equals(q));
         assertFalse(q.equals(p));
         assertFalse(p.equals(null));
         assertTrue(p.equals(q.reverse()));//test that is not passing
    }

}
```

I need to have all of the test cases pass. All of them pass besides the last one where I have to invoke the reverse method. The receiver of the reverse method should not be mutated. For example, I should not put in p(3,5) to be reversed. Everything else works besides the reverse method. If i call p.reverse(); and print out p, it prints in the original order.

Comment: as a sidenote `(obj instanceof DefaultPair)` has an inbuild `null` check, so the previous null check is unnecessary.

Comment: Remove the `reverseFirst` and `reverseSecond` fields.

Comment: also you could remove the `final` modifier from your `first` and `second` fields, as they are logically unchangeble aswell, since there is no setter method.

Comment: @KevinEsche There are known advantages to _adding_ `final`, why should OP _remove_ it?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik i didn´t read the non mutable part at first and thought he wanted to just swap `first` and `second` on the `DefaultPair` instance (which this implementation kind of made me think). As `first` and `second` weren´t touched anywhere else and as there are no getter and setter i thought he could omit the `final` to achive this. But i guess that´s irrelevant now.

Comment: There is a simple misunderstanding on OP's part about the actual requirement. The name of method is kind of misleading, it would be clearer if it was called `getReversed`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `equals()` implementation in DefaultPair checks `first` and `second` field values for equality. But your `reverse()` method only changes the values of `reverseFirst` and `reverseSecond` fields.

Either you need to use `reverseFirst` and `reverseSecond` in `equals()` or change the values of `first` and `second` in `reverse()`

Comment: Also I would reccommend to remove reverseFirst and reverseSecond, and design the metohd reverse to return a new instance of Pair with first and second swapped

Answer (score 1):

I think what's wrong is here:  `F reverse()`, in your situation, F is Integer, but Integer is not what you should return, you should return Pair.

```
p.equals(q.reverse()) is like: pair.equals(Integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully i did understand everything correctly, but i think your reverse method should be looking like this:

```
public DefaultPair<F> reverse() {
   return new DefaultPair<F>(second,first);
   // Here you should return a new instance of `DefaultPair<F>`, 
   // which uses second as first and first as second.
   // Now you are left with an non mutable reversed new instance of DefaultPair

}
```

In the end this would logically also make `reverseFirst` and `reverseSecond` useless in your class, and as though they should be removed.

Comment: I think this did guide me in the right direction, but the test still isn't passing. When I invoke reverse and print after that it still gives me the original pair.

Comment: @ASS466uiuc because you need to store the new instance generated here into a variable. As you mentioned that `DefaultPair` shouldn´t be mutable it is now returning a new reversed instance, which should be a different pair now. Try out just printing `p.reverse()` and you´ll see the new instance beeing different.

Comment: System.out.println(q.reverse()); i did, this was my print line, but moreover the jUnit test still isn't passing

Comment: @ASS466uiuc what should be the result here? That the reversed Pairs are equal to each other? That´s not what you equals method does imply

Comment: the result should be that when q is reversed, it should be equal to the p original. Do you think the problem may be with my equals method?

Comment: @ASS466uiuc yes it is, you only check for equals pairs (first = first and second = second), but never consider equality on reverse pairs (first = second and second = first), though your pairs arent equal.